# Можно вставить видео Iframe в андроид приложение?

Tags: android, iframe

Можно вставить видео Iframe в андроид приложение через html? Нужно вставить видео из сайта через Iframe.....................

Answer (score 2):

Для этого в Android  есть WebView вот короткий пример использования это xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

а это Java код

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/RZTei7UMTPk");

    }

}
```

Comment: ну вот пример видео которое нужно вывести `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RZTei7UMTPk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: @Андрей  дороговтоварищ исправил ,посматрите

Comment: спасибо большое бро, сейчас попробую отпишу

Comment: Хорошо !Получится не беспокойтесь.

Comment: @Андрей, если у вас всё видео - youtube - то есть официальная либа для отображения видео с тытрубы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ето пример, мне не с ютюба надо, спасибо за отклик )))

Comment: @Андрей ну как там ?)

Comment: все работает спасибо))

Comment: @Андрей  удачи в начинаниях!!!

Comment: @elik зря обрадовался , неработает ((

Comment: что пишет ? поччему ?

Comment: я код исправил попробуйте